# How to rotate a rigidBody2d in a fixed period?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, rotation, rigid-bodies

I'm new in Unity development. I have a ball with `RigidBody 2D` on it and i want it to rotate for 1 second. Does not matter the speed. The speed can be automatically.

I want just : at second 0 to be in initial position and at second 1 to be in final position. The rotation can be : 180, 360, 720.. etc degree.

I tried with `angularVelocity` but never stops. I tried with add torque but same. I don't know to handle it.

```
rb.angularVelocity = 180;
```

or

```
rb.AddTorque(90);
```

Comment: you can use angularVelocity and after one second you can set angularVelocity to zero

Comment: How can I know if it's in right position after one second?

Comment: by position you mean rotation?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. In the right rotation

Comment: You might also consider using DoTween https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/27676

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reach a precise rotation after a certain amount of time, it means your rotation speed will be computed automatically. To achieve something like this I'd recommend using a **Coroutine** :

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float targetAngle;
    public float rotationDuration;

    void Update()
    {
        //This is only to test the coroutine
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            StartCoroutine(RotateBall(targetAngle, rotationDuration));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator RotateBall(float a_TargetAngle, float a_Duration)
    {
        Vector3 startLocalEulerAngles = GetComponent<RectTransform>().localEulerAngles;
        Vector3 deltaLocalEulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, a_TargetAngle - startLocalEulerAngles.z);
        float timer = 0.0f;

        while(timer < a_Duration)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            GetComponent<RectTransform>().localEulerAngles = startLocalEulerAngles + deltaLocalEulerAngles * (timer / a_Duration);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }

        GetComponent<RectTransform>().localEulerAngles = startLocalEulerAngles + deltaLocalEulerAngles;
    }
}
```

Comment: what should be `RectTransform`? Because i get that error: `There is no RectTransform attached to the game object.

Comment: There is a 2D game object

Comment: use transform instead of GetComponent<RectTransform>, I don't know what he tried to do

Comment: @luizcarlosfx What I tried to do is reach the _RectTransform_ component which is how unity handles its UI items. My bad for assuming @Gaby used Unity UI for his game (since I use it all the time for 2D I tend to forget you're not forced to). But when using it, I'd rather call `(RectTransform)transform` or `GetComponent<RectTransform>()` instead of simply `transform` in order not to forget the code's dealing with a _RectTransform_ and not a "standard" _Transform_ : simply a matter of preference and clarity in the code ;)

Comment: Yes, I know it's for UI, this is why I said i didn't understand why